# Swift segmented control and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have segmented control as a header of UITableView with cell names. Tableview has different cells with different sizes. When I tap on segment, I do a scroll to specific row in a tableview.

```
segment.valueSelected = { index in
    self.contentTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 1), at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

But how can I change selected index of segmented control when I scroll my tableview? I mean I know how to change index, but the problem is how can I calculate specific offset since all cells has different sizes?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    segment.setSelectIndex(index : ???)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved by

```
let visiblerows = contentTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
if let lastIndex = visiblerows?.last {
   segment.setSelectIndex(index: lastIndex.row, animated: true)
}
```